# Are they both correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

Keep in mind either of the statements occur the next day, that is the context must be considered to be in only past tense and FYI I know "to be" is for present and "to have been" is for past so kindly pls don't gimme that explanation.

> Son, you were supposed to be here at 9:00 PM, what happened?

OR

> Son, you were supposed to have been here at 9:00 PM, what happened?

Comment: If it was the next day then the second would be more likely.  But either is possible.